# Neon: how to run on jdk9?

Tags: eclipse, java-9, eclipse-neon

Just started playing with jdk9 - and kind-of stuck right at the beginning:

- downloaded and extracted eclipse-java-neon-m4a-win32
- installed java 9 support (by dnd from [marketplace](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/java-9-support-beta-neon))
- downloaded and installed jdk9u99 (only the jdk, not the public jre)

At this point, I can run eclipse on my default java (which is 8u60) both with jre/jdk (with/out vm argument in eclipse.ini) and use the java 9 support.

As next step, I wanted to run eclipse with java 9: added the vm-arg to eclipse.ini, now eclipse aborts its startup with a lengthy error log (both ini and log are shown below).

Where's the problem?

My ini:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.200.v20151021-1308.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.300.v20151013-1129
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vm
d:\java\jdk\190_ea\bin\javaw.exe
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
```

The top of the error log (it's > 900k)

```
!SESSION 2016-01-22 14:31:55.974 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.6.0.I20151209-2300
java.version=9-ea
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=de_DE
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.common 4 0 2016-01-22 14:31:57.113
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.equinox.common [143]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.7))"

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:429)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1582)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1562)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1533)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1476)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ant.core 4 0 2016-01-22 14:31:57.175
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.ant.core [61]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.core.variables; bundle-version="[3.1.0,4.0.0)"
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.core.variables; bundle-version="3.2.800.v20130819-1716"; singleton:="true"
       org.eclipse.core.variables [88]
         Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.core.runtime; bundle-version="[3.3.0,4.0.0)"
           -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.core.runtime; bundle-version="3.12.0.v20151104-0048"; singleton:="true"
              org.eclipse.core.runtime [87]
                Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.equinox.common; bundle-version="[3.8.0,4.0.0)"; visibility:="reexport"
                  -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.equinox.common; bundle-version="3.8.0.v20151023-1114"; singleton:="true"
                     org.eclipse.equinox.common [143]
                       Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.7))"

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:429)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1582)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1561)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1533)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1476)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
```

---

**Update**

still no luck with the latest Neon (M6) and 9-ea-113, the logged error has changed, though

```
!SESSION 2016-04-28 16:27:53.344 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.6.0.I20160317-0200
java.version=9-ea
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=de_DE
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2016-04-28 16:28:10.145
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/annotation/PostConstruct
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:386)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:294)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createDefaultHeadlessContext(E4Application.java:490)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createDefaultContext(E4Application.java:504)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createE4Workbench(E4Application.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:627)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:605)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:520)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:670)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:609)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1516)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1489)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/annotation/PostConstruct
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.inject(InjectorImpl.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:375)
    ... 23 more
```

Which looks similar to the one in a [bug report](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=490560). It's marked as fixed in M7.

Comment: Should work with http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops4/Y20160324-1000/

Comment: @wzberger thanks, will try soon

Comment: What do you mean by "only the jdk, not the public jre", did you mix the java 9 jdk and java 7/8 jre? 
That would sound like something that might cause java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Comment: @jan.supol yeah sure I mix, won't have a preview as public standard jre :-) But they should be isolated, I think (and always were in earlier versions)

Comment: I do not know how you mix it, but javax/annotation/PostConstruct is in rt.jar, and in jdk 9 there is not such a file.

Comment: [here](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.6/platform.php#java-9) they say you need to start neon with `-addmods java.se.ee`

Comment: @jan.supol will have a look thanks!

Comment: i just had the same problem. adding -addmods java.se.ee on 2 lines at the end of the .ini file does not work. i get the same: NoClassDefFoundError: javax/annotation/PostConstruct error.

Comment: After "Xmx", you should add "--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM" in "eclipse.ini" according to https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=493761#c83

Answer (score 30):

### **Edit:** You can download the latest version of eclipse which has support for Java 9 - https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/eclipse-packages/

---

I am running Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9-ea+158) and eclipse Version: Neon.2 Release (4.6.2) - Build id: 20161208-0600

Somehow the solutions with `-Djdk.launcher.addmods=` and `-addmods` using values `java.se.ee` or `java.annotations.common` did not work.

**Below is the solution that worked for me:**

```
--add-modules=java.se.ee
```

Source: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBIDE-22417?focusedCommentId=13310535&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-13310535

Comment: For RED ide, I added this line to /opt/RED/RED.ini file

Answer (score 19):

Whoever is facing the same Eclipse crash issue with the Java 11, none of the above solutions seem to work.

Here is the error:

```
org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/annotation/PostConstruct
```

As mentioned here https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=533390, this issue is fixed with the Eclipse Photon 4.8.

Here is the workaround mentioned https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=533390#c22. However, this just a short-term workaround so it's better to update the eclipse to 4.8

**Steps:**

1. Go to eclipse config.ini file, which you find here 
   /Applications/Eclipse_4.7.2
   .app/Contents/Eclipse/configuration/config.ini
2. Add the below content

.

```
org.osgi.framework.system.packages = \
 javax.accessibility,\
 javax.activation,\
 javax.activity,\
 javax.crypto,\
 javax.crypto.interfaces,\
 javax.crypto.spec,\
 javax.imageio,\
 javax.imageio.event,\
 javax.imageio.metadata,\
 javax.imageio.plugins.bmp,\
 javax.imageio.plugins.jpeg,\
 javax.imageio.spi,\
 javax.imageio.stream,\
 javax.jws,\
 javax.jws.soap,\
 javax.lang.model,\
 javax.lang.model.element,\
 javax.lang.model.type,\
 javax.lang.model.util,\
 javax.management,\
 javax.management.loading,\
 javax.management.modelmbean,\
 javax.management.monitor,\
 javax.management.openmbean,\
 javax.management.relation,\
 javax.management.remote,\
 javax.management.remote.rmi,\
 javax.management.timer,\
 javax.naming,\
 javax.naming.directory,\
 javax.naming.event,\
 javax.naming.ldap,\
 javax.naming.spi,\
 javax.net,\
 javax.net.ssl,\
 javax.print,\
 javax.print.attribute,\
 javax.print.attribute.standard,\
 javax.print.event,\
 javax.rmi,\
 javax.rmi.CORBA,\
 javax.rmi.ssl,\
 javax.script,\
 javax.security.auth,\
 javax.security.auth.callback,\
 javax.security.auth.kerberos,\
 javax.security.auth.login,\
 javax.security.auth.spi,\
 javax.security.auth.x500,\
 javax.security.cert,\
 javax.security.sasl,\
 javax.sound.midi,\
 javax.sound.midi.spi,\
 javax.sound.sampled,\
 javax.sound.sampled.spi,\
 javax.sql,\
 javax.sql.rowset,\
 javax.sql.rowset.serial,\
 javax.sql.rowset.spi,\
 javax.swing,\
 javax.swing.border,\
 javax.swing.colorchooser,\
 javax.swing.event,\
 javax.swing.filechooser,\
 javax.swing.plaf,\
 javax.swing.plaf.basic,\
 javax.swing.plaf.metal,\
 javax.swing.plaf.multi,\
 javax.swing.plaf.nimbus,\
 javax.swing.plaf.synth,\
 javax.swing.table,\
 javax.swing.text,\
 javax.swing.text.html,\
 javax.swing.text.html.parser,\
 javax.swing.text.rtf,\
 javax.swing.tree,\
 javax.swing.undo,\
 javax.tools,\
 javax.xml,\
 javax.xml.bind,\
 javax.xml.bind.annotation,\
 javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters,\
 javax.xml.bind.attachment,\
 javax.xml.bind.helpers,\
 javax.xml.bind.util,\
 javax.xml.crypto,\
 javax.xml.crypto.dom,\
 javax.xml.crypto.dsig,\
 javax.xml.crypto.dsig.dom,\
 javax.xml.crypto.dsig.keyinfo,\
 javax.xml.crypto.dsig.spec,\
 javax.xml.datatype,\
 javax.xml.namespace,\
 javax.xml.parsers,\
 javax.xml.soap,\
 javax.xml.stream,\
 javax.xml.stream.events,\
 javax.xml.stream.util,\
 javax.xml.transform,\
 javax.xml.transform.dom,\
 javax.xml.transform.sax,\
 javax.xml.transform.stax,\
 javax.xml.transform.stream,\
 javax.xml.validation,\
 javax.xml.ws,\
 javax.xml.ws.handler,\
 javax.xml.ws.handler.soap,\
 javax.xml.ws.http,\
 javax.xml.ws.soap,\
 javax.xml.ws.spi,\
 javax.xml.ws.spi.http,\
 javax.xml.ws.wsaddressing,\
 javax.xml.xpath,\
 org.ietf.jgss,\
 org.omg.CORBA,\
 org.omg.CORBA_2_3,\
 org.omg.CORBA_2_3.portable,\
 org.omg.CORBA.DynAnyPackage,\
 org.omg.CORBA.ORBPackage,\
 org.omg.CORBA.portable,\
 org.omg.CORBA.TypeCodePackage,\
 org.omg.CosNaming,\
 org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContextExtPackage,\
 org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContextPackage,\
 org.omg.Dynamic,\
 org.omg.DynamicAny,\
 org.omg.DynamicAny.DynAnyFactoryPackage,\
 org.omg.DynamicAny.DynAnyPackage,\
 org.omg.IOP,\
 org.omg.IOP.CodecFactoryPackage,\
 org.omg.IOP.CodecPackage,\
 org.omg.Messaging,\
 org.omg.PortableInterceptor,\
 org.omg.PortableInterceptor.ORBInitInfoPackage,\
 org.omg.PortableServer,\
 org.omg.PortableServer.CurrentPackage,\
 org.omg.PortableServer.POAManagerPackage,\
 org.omg.PortableServer.POAPackage,\
 org.omg.PortableServer.portable,\
 org.omg.PortableServer.ServantLocatorPackage,\
 org.omg.SendingContext,\
 org.omg.stub.java.rmi,\
 org.w3c.dom,\
 org.w3c.dom.bootstrap,\
 org.w3c.dom.css,\
 org.w3c.dom.events,\
 org.w3c.dom.html,\
 org.w3c.dom.ls,\
 org.w3c.dom.ranges,\
 org.w3c.dom.stylesheets,\
 org.w3c.dom.traversal,\
 org.w3c.dom.views,\
 org.w3c.dom.xpath,\
 org.xml.sax,\
 org.xml.sax.ext,\
 org.xml.sax.helpers
```

Comment: Works like a charm for DBever!

Comment: Thanks for the details. Short term solution but saves time.

Comment: This worked although Eclipse takes about 5 minutes to start up now.

Answer (score 11):

To get rid of the `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.annotation.PostConstruct` issue, try adding the following line under `-vmargs` in your `eclipse.ini`:

```
-Djdk.launcher.addmods=java.annotations.common
```

(Will change to `--add-modules=java.annotations.common` in JDK 9 EA build 132)

See https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=493761

UPDATE: Since this answer, more things changed, I am currently running Eclipse with JDK 9 b177 and these added vmargs:
--add-modules=java.xml.bind,java.xml.ws.annotation

Comment: This solution seems not to work on newer builds (build 9+176). However, Pavan Kumar's answer works properly.

Comment: `--add-modules=java.xml.bind,java.xml.ws.annotation` worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

Add the following line at the end of eclipse.ini

```
--add-modules=java.se.ee
```

Comment: please mention the Eclipse version because it is not working with Eclipse Oxygen 3a 2018

Answer (score 3):

## [Eclipse Oxygen.1a (4.7.1a) Release](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/eclipse-packages/)

Since a lot of Q&A's have been marked duplicate of this and the already suggested solutions are nevertheless hacky.

***Update as of 11 October,2017*** - You shall upgrade to the latest [eclipse package](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/eclipse-packages/) Eclipse Oxygen.1a (4.7.1a) which is marked as released and supports Java 9.

Answer (score 1):

Your `eclipse.ini` is wrong for specifying the JVM. First of all, the `-vm` option needs to be near the end, right before any `-vmargs` line. Second, you don't specify the location of the `bin` folder, rather the java executable (or dll). See [the eclipse.ini wiki page](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini) for details (and pay careful attention to the details written there).

By the way, where did you get the info to write `eclipse.ini` the way you did? I'd like to know the source in hopes of correcting that misinformation.

Comment: thanks - guilty of incorrectly copying from https://waynebeaton.wordpress.com/2015/10/18/eclipse-java-9-support-beta-for-mars/ (that's Linux, so might make a difference to my win7 <g>  Now changed the ini as suggested - error is unchanged.

Comment: Bummer, I was hoping (grasping, really) that the other errors were due to not finding the Java 9 VM. Dirk is probably more on track in suspecting the EE resolution is somehow related.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same error I find solution from [Configure Eclipse for Java 9](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Configure_Eclipse_for_Java_9)

Following edit you have to do in eclipse.ini file

1. -vm
   C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9\bin\javaw.exe
2. --add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM

And It will solve your problem.
Your eclipse.ini file look like following:

```
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9\bin\javaw.exe
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. The NoClassDefFoundError shows when you select to build/compile your project with Java 9 JDK. Eclipse is unable to find a required jar file in root JDK folder, so it fails to start completely. After installing the Java 9 support plugin from the marketplace you may be able to start Eclipse, but still you will see a lot of errors and won't be able to compile a single project. The solution (for now) is to switch to Java 9 JRE in "Installed JREs" under "Project Preferences". This fixed everything for me

Taken from [here](https://javatutorial.net/install-java-9-eclipse), you may want to read the full article for more instructions

Answer (score 0):

Adding this in eclipse.ini worked for me

```
--add-modules=java.se.ee   
-XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue sometimes due to having a different version of java in the machine.
I solved this issue to update the .ini file with the correct version.
Below configuration is working for me.

- startup
  plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.4.0.v20161219-1356.jar
- vm
  C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\bin\javaw.exe
- vmargs
- Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
- Xmx2G
- Xms200m
- XX:MaxPermSize=512m

Answer (score 0):

I had got the same error. 
org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/annotation/PostConstruct

Resolved it by uninstalling all different versions of java and installed just **1.8.0_231**.

Worked finally.

Java 8 installation link -
https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

Scala IDE for **Eclipse:- version - 4.7.0**
http://scala-ide.org/download/sdk.html