# Android Device Monitor not running with JDK 9 on MAC OS X even after updating eclipse.ini

Tags: java, eclipse, java-9, android-device-monitor

Now JDK 9 is officially released, i've upgraded my Mac OSX to run Java SE Development Kit 9.

Android Device Monitor ( `/Library/Android/sdk/tools/monitor` ) is no longer working. Logs here:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-09-24 13:30:55.822
`enter code here`!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to acquire application service. Ensure that the org.eclipse.core.runtime bundle is resolved and started (see config.ini).
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
```

I have been able to fix a similar issue for Eclipse Oxygen by adding

```
--add-modules=java.se.ee
```

in `eclipse.ini`, as explain in this SO answer
[Neon: how to run on jdk9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34947994/neon-how-to-run-on-jdk9). This fixes 100% the Eclipse issue, so now I can run eclipse without problems, but the Android device monitor is still not running.

I have already tried also the solution ["Unable to acquire application service" error while launching Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493415/unable-to-acquire-application-service-error-while-launching-eclipse) without success.

Is there anything else that must be configured?

Comment: same issue, tried all the possible solutions Everthing working fine except android device monitor

Comment: Android Device Monitor does not support Java 9 yet. I had to reconfigure Java 8 as the default JDK and JRE to have ADM working.

Similar discussion here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46577896/5517547

Comment: This solution is same with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46577610/android-device-monitor-not-opening/49427375#49427375 . So I answered https://stackoverflow.com/a/49427375/967009