# Android Device Monitor not opening

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am unable to run Android Monitor. I am using Android Studio.  Not Eclipse.

- When I attempt to open it in the terminal using  sudo ./monitor, I see the following warning, then it shows

> WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred WARNING:
>   Illegal reflective access by
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.BaseStorage
>   (file:/Users/kidus11/Library/Android/sdk/tools/lib/monitor-x86_64/plugins/org.eclipse.osgi_3.8.2.v20130124-134944.jar)
>   to method java.net.URLClassLoader.addURL(java.net.URL) WARNING: Please
>   consider reporting this to the maintainers of
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.BaseStorage WARNING: Use
>   --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations WARNING: All illegal access operations will be
>   denied in a future release

- I have Java version 9, as well has Javac 9
- I have installed the latest version of JDK or JRE

Here is the tag I see every time I try to open Android Device Monitor

> !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-10-04 20:18:12.531 !MESSAGE
>   Application error !STACK 1 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to
>   acquire application service. Ensure that the org.eclipse.core.runtime
>   bundle is resolved and started (see config.ini).  at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:74)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
>     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)   at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)  at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I am using android studio...

Comment: You can see my answer below that is work for me.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Android Studio does not support Java 9 yet. 
Install JDK 8 and update your studio configurations to point the jre for 8.

Then ensure that you are not setting your JAVA_HOME to 9 yet either.
Lastly, make sure you eclipse is not running somewhere on your machine taking ownership of the ADB already.

Comment: How do I update my studio configuration to point to the jre for 8? and How do I ensure that I am not setting my JAVA_HOME to 9? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Project Structure --> SDK Location

Comment: Environment variable JAVA_HOME is either in your ~/.bash_profile if on mac or linux otherwise it is in the windows properties environment variables. You set JAVA_HOME to the JRE pathway of your java install

Comment: Well....I tried what you suggested. And still the error persisted. Thearefore, I had to reinstiall android studio to fix the error.

Comment: ok so you are pointing to JRE 8 now then? Not sure why new install would matter unless you clicked custom install the first time and pointed it oddly, which I can't imagine you would have done.

Comment: Yes, I am using JRE 8, and it is working fine with new install. But it did not work with the previous install, so I guess I somehow changed the setting or something when installed android studio back then.

Answer (score 8):

Newest Android Studio Bundle comes with its own JRE (under `<ANDROID_STUDIO>/jre` and this is the recommended JRE to work with (look at File / Project Structure / SDK Location).

Likewise, a simple option is to create a symbolic link under the monitor tools to keep JRE in line with Android Studio even getting an update.

For MAC or Linux:

```
#ln -s <ANDROID_STUDIO>/jre <SDK>/tools/lib/monitor-x86_64/jre
```

32 bits:

```
#ln -s <ANDROID_STUDIO>/jre <SDK>/tools/lib/monitor-x86/jre
```

Then the ddms monitor works for both ways:  from Studio IDE (Tools / Android / ADM) or command line  (`<SDK>tools/./monitor`)

Comment: It fixed in my case. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, The Newest Android Studio Bundle comes with its own JRE (under `C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre`).

So, You can just copy this `jre` folder and paste it to here:
`C:\Users\<Username>\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\lib\monitor-x86_64`

And now in android studio go to the Tools -> Android -> Android Device Monitor.

Or you can prefer this link [Resolve Android Device Monitor issue](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X6KXFVvf8Yc)

Comment: this work for me having exclusively Java 9 Installed.**Thanks**,

Comment: Wow in thousands of answers this is the only which worked (with only Java 9 installed). Easy and fast. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You modify Info.plist file in monitor binary directory.

```
Path example in Mac: 
/Users/{username}/Library/Android/sdk/tools/lib/monitor.app/Contents/Info.plist
```

Add -vm key of bundled java path into `<key>Eclipse</key><array>`.(There is a comment.You read it.)

```
-vm key example

<string>-vm</string><string>/Applications/Android\ 
Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java</string>
```

Comment: This is the only approach that worked for me on Mojave. Installed Java 8 through brew. Then added

`<string>-vm</string><string>/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_172.jdk/Contents/Home/bin</string>`

Comment: sorry better use `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java`

with version 8 the gui starts, but freezes

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what is your use case for Android Device Monitor, but apparently since Android Studio 3.0. most components of the Android Device Monitor are deprecated:

https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/monitor.html

There are other tools that can be used such as Android Profiler...

So maybe it is not really necessary to try to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

- reason: `monitor` not support `java 8+`
- solution: change Java (your java 9) to Java 8

#### Append

##### how set Java 8 in macOS

- find java home path

```
 /usr/libexec/java_home -V
Matching Java Virtual Machines (4):
    11.0.2 (x86_64) "Oracle Corporation" - "OpenJDK 11.0.2" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-11.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.8.333.02 (x86_64) "Oracle Corporation" - "Java" /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home
    1.8.0_112 (x86_64) "Oracle Corporation" - "Java SE 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_112.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.7.0_79 (x86_64) "Oracle Corporation" - "Java SE 7" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-11.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home
```

- added into boot script

```
 cat ~/.bashrc | grep JAVA
#export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
#export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-11.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home
#export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_112.jdk/Contents/Home
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```