# Does Eclipse Neon support Java 9?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-neon, eclipse-oxygen

Does Eclipse Neon support Java 9? I know Eclipse Oxygen can be used but we have some constraints to not use other Eclipse than Neon.

We are using Maven for Building our J2EE project and Git for source control.

I appreciate if you can back your answer with some links/proofs. Thanks!

Comment: IMHO, the constraints of not updating software should be reconsidered with regard to security vulnerabilities, bugs and performance issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Does eclipse Neon support Java 9?*

It depends what you mean by "support". If you mean "*Is the use of Java 9 officially supported with Neon?*" then the answer is no. For example, see [this DZone article](https://dzone.com/articles/working-with-java-9-in-eclipse):

> You need an Oxygen-based install of Eclipse – ensure you’re using the
>   R version and not milestone or integration builds.

Also, from [Eclipse's site](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Configure_Eclipse_for_Java_9):

> Users who install Eclipse Oxygen 4.7.1a are able to launch with Java 9
>   and get Java 9 support

But if you mean "*Is it possible to get Java 9 running under Neon?*" then the answer is yes. Here's a snippet from an article titled [Eclipse Java™ 9 Support (BETA) for Neon](https://waynebeaton.wordpress.com/2015/10/18/eclipse-java-9-support-beta-for-mars/) from a brave soul who did it back in 2015!...

> I downloaded the early access version of Java 9 JDK from java.net in
>   the form of a tar.gz file that I decompressed into a local directory:
>   /home/apps/jdk1.9.0. I made no other changes to my system.
>
> I downloaded the Eclipse SDK 4.6 (Neon) M2 from the Eclipse Platform
>   downloads and decompressed it into its own directory. I made a small
>   change to the eclipse.ini file to make the new configuration run using
>   the Java 9 runtime...

Of course, that was done with an early access release of Java 9, and I wouldn't automatically assume that Neon will still work with the latest release of Java 9.

~~~~~~~~~

**Update:**

I just noticed this SO question titled [Neon: how to run on jdk9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34947994/neon-how-to-run-on-jdk9?rq=1) which may offer further useful information.