# "Application Error" on Eclipse when opening an extension (still able to open Eclipse itself)

Tags: windows, eclipse, launch

I'm working with an appication named Capella, which is an extension of Eclipse. This is the Capella's folder (I'm using Window 10, 64 bit by the way):
[Capella's folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WMnzi.png)

This extension requires Eclipse and of course Java which have appropriate version (so i used both 64bit version). I got "see the log file" error on trying to launch it. So here is my .log file:

```
       ' !SESSION 2018-06-05 10:20:54.986 ----------------------------------
-------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=10.0.1
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2018-06-05 10:21:16.955
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:             
javax/annotation/PostConstruct
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:386)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:294)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:162)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createDefaultHeadlessContext(E4Application.java:490)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createDefaultContext(E4Ap
plication.java:504)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createE4Workbench(E4Application.java:203)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:632)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:610)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:148)
at org.polarsys.capella.core.platform.sirius.ui.app.CapellaApplication.start(CapellaApplication.java:116)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:673)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:610)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1519)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1492)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/annotation/PostConstruct
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.inject(InjectorImpl.java:151)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:375)
... 23 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.annotation.PostConstruct cannot be found by org.eclipse.e4.core.di_1.6.1.v20160712-0927
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:410)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:372)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:364)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:161)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 25 more

!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2018-06-05 10:21:16.970
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/annotation/PreDestroy
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.disposed(InjectorImpl.java:426)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.Requestor.disposed(Requestor.java:154)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.ContextObjectSupplier$ContextInjectionListener.update(ContextObjectSupplier.java:78)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.TrackableComputationExt.update(TrackableComputationExt.java:111)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.TrackableComputationExt.handleInvalid(TrackableComputationExt.java:74)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.dispose(EclipseContext.java:176)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.osgi.EclipseContextOSGi.dispose(EclipseContextOSGi.java:106)
at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.osgi.EclipseContextOSGi.bundleChanged(EclipseContextOSGi.java:139)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:903)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEventPrivileged(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:213)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEvent(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:120)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEvent(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:112)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainerAdaptor.publishModuleEvent(EquinoxContainerAdaptor.java:156)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.publishEvent(Module.java:476)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStop(Module.java:634)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.stop(Module.java:498)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.SystemModule.stop(SystemModule.java:202)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$SystemBundle$EquinoxSystemModule$1.run(EquinoxBundle.java:165)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.annotation.PreDestroy cannot be found by org.eclipse.e4.core.di_1.6.1.v20160712-0927
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:410)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:372)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:364)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:161)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 21 more`
```

Otherwise, I have no problem on lauching Eclipse and Yakindu which is another extension of Eclipse. I do some research and most of them is about not be able to run Eclipse either, which is not my case. Some suggest to delete the .metadata folder which is not worked either for me cause it's still created when I launch Capella again.
Do you guy have any other suggests? I will be appreciate for your help!
Thanks!

Comment: Is this a separate installation of Eclipse from your main one? The error is due to trying to use an older Eclipse with Java 10 (or 9). See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34947994/neon-how-to-run-on-jdk9)

Comment: No, it's not. This is the Capella's folder when I extracted it. You can find Capella application on this link: https://polarsys.org/capella/download.html The "eclipse.exe" actually is Capella which based on Java and run on Eclipse.

Comment: So you mean I should use an earlier version of Java like Java 8 instead of 10?

Comment: You can either use Java 8 or modify the Capella ini file as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34947994/neon-how-to-run-on-jdk9)

Comment: Thank you so much greg-449! I have added this line: "--add-modules=java.se.ee" at the end of the file .ini like in the forum and It works perfectly! Thank you so much again, you save my day.